# Adding hook to model creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

I have a model class Person, and I create instances of them using:

```
person = Person.create!
```

Now I want to say that this person was born in California, USA, but in this peculiar way:

```
person = Person.create!({:name => "Matt", :born => "USCA"})
```

This means there are two characters to identify the country and another two characters to identify the state.
But I don't want to store the string in the database, I want to store in a structured way, like:

| Name | Country | State      |
| Matt | USA     | California |

Where can I parse the string to assign the country and state based on it? Which method in the model?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
before_save :parse_country_code

def parse_country_code
  if born_changed?
    self.state = ...
    self.country = ...
  end
  true # avoid cancelling the callback chain
end
```

You may also find [ActiveRecord::Aggregations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html) useful. With that you could consolidate your parsing and other logic to another class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `before_save` callback — something like this:

```
attr_accessible :born

before_save :parse_location

def parse_location
    # parsing here…
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ActiveRecord [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) module